# Fenics import Error in Pycharm (Python 3 and higher)

Tags: pycharm

I currently set up a fresh Ubuntu 16.04. First things i installed is Pycharm and created a venv, with interpreter Python 3.6. I tried to install and import Fenics, which gives me the message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'fenics'
```

I installed Fenics with pip, which seemed to work. Interestingly I am able to import Fenics, when Python 2.7 Interpreter is used. Adding Fenics to the project interpreter results in non-importable package and same error message.
I also installed Fenics with Docker, which seems to work, but I want to avoid using Docker repositories. How can I import Fenics while using Pycharm with Interpreter Python3.6?

Thanks in advance,
DaniLu

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by installing Python3 dijitso, dolfin, ffc, instant via Synaptic. Also only works with Python3.5 Interpreter. Have a good time guys.